# How to batch train a CNN with Keras fit_generator?

Tags: keras, generator, conv-neural-network, training-data

Apologies if this is the wrong place to raise my issue (please help me out with where best to raise it if that's the case). I'm a novice with Keras and Python so hope responses have that in mind.

I'm trying to train a CNN steering model that takes images as input. It's a fairly large dataset, so I created a data generator to work with fit_generator(). It's not clear to me how to make this method trains on batches, so I assumed that the generator has to return batches to fit_generator(). The generator looks like this:

```
def gen(file_name, batchsz = 64):
    csvfile = open(file_name)
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    batchCount = 0
    while True:
        for line in reader:
            inputs = []
            targets = []
            temp_image = cv2.imread(line[1]) # line[1] is path to image
            measurement = line[3] # steering angle
            inputs.append(temp_image)
            targets.append(measurement)
            batchCount += 1
            if batchCount >= batchsz:
                batchCount = 0
                X = np.array(inputs)
                y = np.array(targets)
                yield X, y
        csvfile.seek(0)
```

It reads a csv file containing telemetry data (steering angle etc) and paths to image samples, and returns arrays of size: batchsz
The call to fit_generator() looks like this:

```
tgen = gen('h:/Datasets/dataset14-no.zero.speed.trn.csv', batchsz = 128) # Train data generator
vgen = gen('h:/Datasets/dataset14-no.zero.speed.val.csv', batchsz = 128) # Validation data generator
try:
    model.fit_generator(
        tgen,
        samples_per_epoch=113526,
        nb_epoch=6,
        validation_data=vgen,
        nb_val_samples=20001
    )
```

The dataset contains 113526 sample points yet the model training update output reads like this (for example):

```
  1020/113526 [..............................] - ETA: 27737s - loss: 0.0080
  1021/113526 [..............................] - ETA: 27723s - loss: 0.0080
  1022/113526 [..............................] - ETA: 27709s - loss: 0.0080
  1023/113526 [..............................] - ETA: 27696s - loss: 0.0080
```

Which appears to be training sample by sample (stochastically?).
The resultant model is useless. I previously trained on a much smaller dataset using .fit() with the whole dataset loaded into memory, and that produced a model that at least works even if poorly. Clearly something is wrong with my fit_generator() approach. Will be very grateful for some help with this.

Comment: `samples_per_epoch` should be equal to `total_samples / batch_size` as suggested in [keras documentation](https://keras.io/models/sequential/). `samples_per_epoch` specifies how many times the generator is called before an epoch is considered completed, it doesn't know what `batch_size` you are using

Comment: Thanks @gionni. Updated from Keras 1.0.2 to latest. The fit-generator() params make more sense with this version.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
for line in reader:
    inputs = []
    targets = []
```

... is resetting your batch for every line in the csv files. You're not training with your entire data, but with just a single sample in 128.

Suggestion:

```
for line in reader:

    if batchCount == 0:
        inputs = []
        targets = []  
    ....
    ....
```

---

As someone commented, the in fit generator, `samples_per_epoch` should be equal to `total_samples / batchsz`

Even though, I think your loss should be going down anyway. If it isn't, there might still be another problem in the code, perhaps in the way you load the data, or in the model's initialization or structure.

Try to plot your images and print the data in the generator:

```
for X,y in tgen: #careful, this is an infinite loop, make it stop

    print(X.shape[0]) # is this really the number of batches you expect?

    for image in X:
        ...some method to plot X so you can see it, or just print     

    print(y)
```

Check if the yielded values are ok with what you expect them to be.

Comment: "... is resetting your batch for every line in the csv files." doh! should have spotted that one. Wierd because I have some test code to print out the yeilded arrays, and they're batches of the right size and sequence.

Comment: About the loss, recently I had a problem with a "frozen" loss. I decided to train just one sample over and over for many epochs and suddenly the loss found its way down. Then I introduced other examples gradually and it started training properly. I guess the model was too complex or I hadn't initialized my weights properly, so it took longer to show some interesting results.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Seems to be training ok now. The GPU load is pretty low though, as though GPU is waiting on the script.